# Deploy application to AWS

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services

I am trying to deploy my application to AWS, when I delete Migration folder, and type Enable-Migration and change AutomaticMigrationEnable = true;
After that I go to Publish to AWS, after couple of minutes I got error

```
Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-0L8HK6U\denni'.
  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD.
Failed to connect to server DESKTOP-0L8HK6U\SQLEXPRESS.
Cannot open database "MojaBaza" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-0L8HK6U\denni'.
```

**Connection String for Amazon**

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Jericho" connectionString="Data Source=demodb.c5sevdrlkzev.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com,1433;User ID=user;Initial Catalog=user;Password=user123;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

**Database connection**

```
   <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Jericho" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Jericho.mdf; Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

I don't know why is looking for database called MojaBaza. 
Where I made mistake guys ? Any help ?

Comment: Not enough information to answer. Post your application code, summarising your data access approach.

Comment: what kind of code you need ?

Comment: The code where you create database connections. *Something* is trying to connect to that database. You're the only person who has that information.

Comment: I update my  question. You can check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with security group of your rds where CIDR /IP - Inbound Rule may be changed make it 0.0.0.0/0 this solved my issue hope it is useful

Comment: Where is CIDP/IP ? I couldn't find this ?

Comment: connect section in your rds service

Comment: No, still have a problem

Comment: When I try to login with this data to SSMS its login fine, but when I try to deploy I get error

Comment: Cannot connect to the database 'MojaBaza'.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CANNOT_CONNECT_TO_DATABASE.
Object of type 'dbFullSql' and path 'data source=DESKTOP-0L8HK6U\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=MojaBaza;integrated security=True;user id=awsuser;pooling=False' cannot be created.
Failed to connect to server DESKTOP-0L8HK6U\SQLEXPRESS.
Cannot open database "MojaBaza" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-0L8HK6U\denni'.